# Is it possible to change Geoserver context-root?

Tags: geoserver

Basically, instead of hosting Geoserver at `https://hostname/geoserver`, can it be hosted at `https://hostname/another-geoserver-context-root`?

I've tried to rename `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/geoserver` to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/another-geoserver-context-root` and the WebUI seems to work but not the Rest API.

I am using this docker image here: https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/geoserver

docker-compose.yml fragment: https://github.com/bird-house/birdhouse-deploy-ouranos/blob/70d6f2e019b083dfb6a80ff62b5eb105ae302470/ouranos-config/docker-compose-extra.yml#L22-L53

Could the error below be caused by one of the plugin we enabled?  See `docker-compose-extra.yml` fragment above.

When context-root is `/geoserver` no error in the logs server-side:

```
10 Mar 05:07:07 INFO   [rest.catalog] - DELETE workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[pc2]                                                                           
10 Mar 05:07:08 INFO   [rest.catalog] - Added workspace pc2                                                                                               
10 Mar 05:07:08 INFO   [rest.catalog] - POST workspace pc2                                                                                                
10 Mar 05:07:08 CONFIG [platform.resource] - Notifying ENTRY_MODIFY change on /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers. Created: 0, removed: 253, modified: 0
10 Mar 05:07:08 INFO   [rest.catalog] - Auto-configuring coverage store: scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00
10 Mar 05:07:12 INFO   [rest.catalog] - PUT coverage scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00,CoverageInfoImpl[scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00]
10 Mar 05:07:12 INFO   [rest.catalog] - POST Style scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00
10 Mar 05:07:12 INFO   [gwc.layer] - Truncating default style for layer pc2:scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00, as it changed from raster to pc2:scen
gen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00
10 Mar 05:07:12 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - Saving GeoSeverTileLayer pc2:scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00
10 Mar 05:07:12 INFO   [rest.catalog] - PUT layer pc2:scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00
```

Corresponding logs client-side:

```
We will use the 'external' method, mapping /data to /opt/geoserver/data_dir.                                                                              
Workspace 'pc2' deleted                                                                                                                                   
Workspace 'pc2' created                                                                                                                                   
/data/netcdf/spatial/scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00.nc /opt/geoserver/data_dir/netcdf/spatial/scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00.nc
Created: scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00
```

When context-root is `/another-geoserver-context-root`, I get this error server-side:

```
10 Mar 05:15:08 INFO   [rest.catalog] - DELETE workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[pc2]                                    
10 Mar 05:15:08 CONFIG [platform.resource] - Notifying ENTRY_MODIFY change on /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers. Created: 0, removed: 15, modified: 0
10 Mar 05:15:08 INFO   [rest.catalog] - Added workspace pc2                                                                                     
10 Mar 05:15:08 INFO   [rest.catalog] - POST workspace pc2                                                                     
10 Mar 05:15:08 ERROR  [geoserver.rest] - Unsupported format: netcdf, available formats are: [dted, envihdr, rpftoc, imagemosaic, geotiff, imagepyramid, s
rp, arcgrid, rst, erdasimg, vrt, worldimage, nitf, aig, ehdr, geopackage (mosaic)]                                                    
org.geoserver.rest.RestException 400 BAD_REQUEST: Unsupported format: netcdf, available formats are: [dted, envihdr, rpftoc, imagemosaic, geotiff, imagepy
ramid, srp, arcgrid, rst, erdasimg, vrt, worldimage, nitf, aig, ehdr, geopackage (mosaic)]                                         
        at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.getCoverageFormat(CoverageStoreFileController.java:307)                        
        at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.coverageStorePut(CoverageStoreFileController.java:143)
```

Corresponding error on client-side:

```
We will use the 'external' method, mapping /data to /opt/geoserver/data_dir.
Workspace 'pc2' deleted
Workspace 'pc2' created
/data/netcdf/spatial/scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00.nc /opt/geoserver/data_dir/netcdf/spatial/scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00.nc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scripts/provision_geoserver_data.py", line 189, in <module>
    create_raster(path, remote_path)
  File "/scripts/provision_geoserver_data.py", line 52, in create_raster
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error:  for url: https://lvupavicsmaster.ouranos.ca/ogc-geoserver/rest/workspaces/pc2/coveragestores/scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00/external.netcdf?coverageName=scengen_heat_wave_frequency_class1_qc00
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have the netcdf extension installed, it's nothing to do with the context name which works as you'd expect

Comment: It is installed and working, the proof is the exact same instance, when configure with `/geoserver` works !  It's only when configured with `/another-geoserver-context-root` that it does not work.

Comment: I found the fix to my problem. It is related to the specific docker image I use.

The fix is described in this PR https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver/pull/507

Comment: then write and accept an answer to this question

Comment: I did write that answer but it was deleted by https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters, not sure why so I had to leave that answer as a comment.